# Why last colunm right aligned in align environment

Tags: align

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{spacing}{0}
\begin{align*}
\texttt{0}\quad&\texttt{11}\quad&\texttt{A}\\
\texttt{1}\quad&\texttt{4}\quad&\texttt{ACACGAGA}\\
\texttt{2}\quad&\texttt{6}\quad&\texttt{ACGAGA}\\
\texttt{3}\quad&\texttt{9}\quad&\texttt{AGA}\\
\texttt{4}\quad&\texttt{1}\quad&\texttt{ATCACACGAGA}\\
\texttt{5}\quad&\texttt{3}\quad&\texttt{CACACGAGA}\\
\texttt{6}\quad&\texttt{5}\quad&\texttt{CACGAGA}\\
\texttt{7}\quad&\texttt{0}\quad&\texttt{CATCACACGAGA}\\
\texttt{8}\quad&\texttt{7}\quad&\texttt{CGAGA}\\
\texttt{9}\quad&\texttt{10}\quad&\texttt{GA}\\
\texttt{10}\quad&\texttt{8}\quad&\texttt{GAGA}\\
\texttt{11}\quad&\texttt{2}\quad&\texttt{TCACACGAGA}
\end{align*}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

and using overleaf the result looks like[image]

What to do if I want last colunm left-aligned? thanks a lot

Comment: The output does not look like it would require math mode at all, so why not use a regular tabular with three columns?

Comment: @leandriis thanks, that's works for me now. But I'm still curious though

Comment: Align alternates between right and left aligned columns, so this is why your first and third column ade right aligned while the second one is left aligned. To overcome this, you could use && instead of a single & in between entries of the second and third column. This would leave the third, right aligned column empty and shift the corresponding entries to a four left aligned column.

Comment: `n` alignment points in an align or alignat environment require `2n-1` ampersands: one to introduce each new alignment column but the first, and one to set the alignment point in its alignment column.

Answer (score 2):

you should be using `tabular` here as all entries are text not math but to answer the question, all AMS alignments are like an `array` with a preamble `r@{}lr@{}lr@{}lr@{}lr@{}l...`  That is pairs of columns alternating right and left aligned, with space between each pair.

This means that input such as

```
 x&=y  &  1+1&=2 \\
 a&=b  &  2+1&=3 \\
```

typesets as two equations on each line with the left hand sides of each equation being right aligned towards the = and the right hand side of each equation being left aligned towards the =, with space added to separate the equations on each line.

Answer (score 1):

As @leandriis has already observed, using an `align*` environment does not appear to be a natural idea, especially as there are no math aspects to the table. I suggest you use a three-column `tabular` environment instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\ttfamily}r >{\ttfamily}r >{\ttfamily}l @{}}
0  & 11 & A \\
1  &  4 & ACACGAGA \\
2  &  6 & ACGAGA \\
3  &  9 & AGA \\
4  &  1 & ATCACACGAGA \\
5  &  3 & CACACGAGA \\
6  &  5 & CACGAGA \\
7  &  0 & CATCACACGAGA \\
8  &  7 & CGAGA \\
9  & 10 & GA \\
10 &  8 & GAGA \\
11 &  2 & TCACACGAGA
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```